# PC starts in loop but never gets to post

Tags: motherboard

I tried to upgrade my PC which was working fine for more than 8 years:

- Mono Gigabyte Z170
- CPU i5 6600
- PSU 750w
- RAM 32GB ddr4 2xxxmhz upgrade to 64GB 3000mhz

And it worked perfectly first boot. Then I decided to upgrade more. I had a Gigabyte RTX 3080Ti vision that I got back after RMA but I had bought another meanwhile but it did not fit in the case, so I bought a new case and because I had also bought a few years ago a Mobo Gigabyte z370 Aorus ultra gaming 2.0 because it was on sale and I was very satisfied with another PC with a Gigabyte Z370 Aorus Gaming 5.

So I unbuild my PC took the CPU i5 6600 mount it on the Mobo Z370 Aorus Ultra Gaming 2.0 installed my SSD with the OS, put the 4 stick of RAM 3000mhz that worked perfectly on the Z170XP SLI, put the RTX graphic card, switch on and the nightmare started.

The new build was looping starting all light up but switching off by itself before posting and starting again. I tried every fix to isolate the problem even with all the system out of the case, until I gave up and decided to put back everything on my Gigabyte Z170 motherboard, only using the new case to be able to fit the RTX, and the nightmare kept going on, same issue with my old rig that was working perfectly.

If I disconnect everything except the CPU it seems that it does not loop anymore, but immediately when I put any of the 4 RAM sticks even just one in any slot and only have that connected, again it goes in a loop. So I thought it was the case but I already tried to eliminate the case when I built the first upgrade.

The PSU - I tested it with a power supply tester and all voltages are fine. What else can I try? Could it be that the CPU that was not listed as compatible of the Z370 Ultra Gaming 2, I found out that after but it is listed as compatible with the Z370 Ultra Game Wifi. So could it be that the CPU got damaged or corrupted and now it repeating the same issue even and the Mobo it has always been the last 10 years or so?

Comment: Maybe a motherboard firmware update is needed?